# Pandas concat() returns empty DataFrame when on DataFrame is changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have two DataFrames, COMMODITY and df_new (I know the naming is weird) and in my first script these DataFrames look like this:

```
COMMODITY
date
2023-01-03    775.50
2023-01-04    745.50
2023-01-05    746.75
2023-01-06    743.50
2023-01-09    741.50
               ...  
2023-07-18    670.75
2023-07-19    727.75
2023-07-20    727.00
2023-07-21    697.50
2023-07-24    757.50
Name: value, Length: 143, dtype: float64

df_new
             Pos_Neg
date                
2019-02-08  1.451702
2019-02-20 -1.636057
2019-02-26 -0.048959
2019-03-07  0.189759
2019-03-08  0.456263
...              ...
2023-07-21  0.075729
2023-07-22  1.201473
2023-07-23  1.397099
2023-07-24  1.009405
2023-07-25 -0.298883

[858 rows x 1 columns]
```

And then I concat these two with this line:

```
merger = pd.concat([COMMODITY, df_new], axis=1, join='inner')
```

This works fine. Now I have a second script, in which COMMODITY is changed to:

```
COMMODITY
date
2014-01-02    209.163498
2014-01-03    208.009465
2014-01-06    209.302691
2014-01-07    206.696035
2014-01-08    205.623171
                 ...    
2023-07-20    253.973427
2023-07-21    249.276062
2023-07-24    261.691134
2023-07-25    260.329869
2023-07-26    262.250000
Name: value, Length: 2439, dtype: float64
```

That's the only difference, but when I concat this the same way, it only returns an empty DataFrame. What is the problem?

This is how I create COMMODITY:

```
COMMODITY = pd.read_sql( price_sql, con=new_pred, parse_dates=['date_id'])
COMMODITY = COMMODITY.set_index('date')
COMMODITY = COMMODITY[::-1]
COMMODITY = COMMODITY.drop_duplicates()
COMMODITY = COMMODITY.groupby(COMMODITY.index)['value'].apply(lambda x : x.median())
    
COMMODITY.index = COMMODITY.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

In the first script the further manipulation of merger is like that:

```
merger['COMAN'] = merger['Pos_Neg']
merger['commodity'] = Target
merger['arrow'] = merger.value + (merger.Pos_Neg * 3)
merger['date'] = merger.index
merger['feature_id'] = feature_id
```

with the result (I know Pos_Neg and COMAN are duplicates, but it has it reasons):

```
             value   Pos_Neg     COMAN commodity       arrow        date  \
date                                                                       
2023-01-03  775.50  0.577601  0.577601     Wheat  777.232802  2023-01-03   
2023-01-04  745.50  0.431001  0.431001     Wheat  746.793003  2023-01-04   
2023-01-05  746.75  0.100048  0.100048     Wheat  747.050145  2023-01-05   
2023-01-06  743.50  0.368427  0.368427     Wheat  744.605281  2023-01-06   
2023-01-09  741.50 -0.833180 -0.833180     Wheat  739.000460  2023-01-09   
...            ...       ...       ...       ...         ...         ...   
2023-07-18  670.75 -0.637585 -0.637585     Wheat  668.837244  2023-07-18   
2023-07-19  727.75  1.191043  1.191043     Wheat  731.323128  2023-07-19   
2023-07-20  727.00  0.456187  0.456187     Wheat  728.368560  2023-07-20   
2023-07-21  697.50  0.075848  0.075848     Wheat  697.727543  2023-07-21   
2023-07-24  757.50  1.009524  1.009524     Wheat  760.528572  2023-07-24   

            feature_id  
date                    
2023-01-03   554884128  
2023-01-04   554884128  
2023-01-05   554884128  
2023-01-06   554884128  
2023-01-09   554884128  
...                ...  
2023-07-18   554884128  
2023-07-19   554884128  
2023-07-20   554884128  
2023-07-21   554884128  
2023-07-24   554884128  

[142 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: (1) How did you change `COMMODITY`? (2) Confirm that the indices of the two series overlap.

Comment: @ifly6 The indices overlap (see the 2023-07-24), I edited my post with how I create `COMMODITY`

Comment: `strftime` creates a string representation of dates and not actual datetime. It is unclear why you call it. Are you trying to normalize time?

Comment: Print the type of both data frames' indices

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that when you are Concatenating in the second script the df_new 'date' index doesn't have common values with your COMMODITY 'date' index and as a result the returning DataFrame is empty.

This is because you are using 'inner' as your join.

If thats not the case could you add resulting merged DataFrame from your first script and also df_new from the second script in your original question.

Comment: The indices do overlap, so I added the resulting table.